# When does the Weekly XP Bonus reset in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

As the title says, when does the Weekly XP Bonus reset in CS:GO?

All the information I can find online isn't precise enough. Most common results just say "Wednesday" without time, while some say "Wednesday at 3 AM", which is completely useless without a time zone specified.

Answer (score 1):

The exact time the timer resets doesn't seem to be public information, and while there's a consensus on the reset being whenever it's Wednesday on PST (since Valve HQ is in Washington state), there doesn't seem to be one for the time itself. It could very well be that there isn't a fixed time, but instead a 24 (or less) hour window.